# Struct Array passed as parameter to read() issue

Tags: c, file-io

I have a struct defined as

```
struct my_struct {
    struct hdr_str hdr;
    char *content; 
};
```

I am trying to pass the content in my_struct of the first element in my_struct by nesting it all as a parameter to read()

what I have is

```
struct my_struct[5];
```

read is defined as

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

and I am trying to pass it as

```
read(fd, my_struct[0].content, count)
```

But I am receiving -1 as a return value, with errno = EFAULT (bad address)

Any idea how to make read read into a char * in a struct array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to allocate memory for `read` to copy data into.

If you know the maximum size of data you'll read, you could change my_struct to

```
struct my_struct {
    struct hdr_str hdr;
    char content[MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH]; 
};
```

where `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH` is #define'd by you to your known max length.

Alternatively, allocate `my_struct.content` on demand once you know how many bytes to read

```
my_struct.content = malloc(count);
read(fd, my_struct[0].content, count);
```

If you do this, make sure to later use `free` on my_struct.content to return its memory to the system.